# Finding characteristics of PDE using method of characteristics

Tags: partial-differential-equations, initial-value-problems, characteristics, cauchy-problem

Consider the IVP
\begin{equation}
xu_x-yu_y=xu\\
u(s,s^2)=1 \; \forall s\in \mathbb{R}
\end{equation}

I am trying to solve this quasilinear PDE using the method of characteristics, such that I have to solve the following
\begin{equation}
\frac{dx}{dt}=x,\;\;\frac{dy}{dt}=-y,\;\; \frac{dz}{dt}=xz\\
x(s,s^2)=s,\; y(s,s^2)=s^2,\; z(s,s^2)=1
\end{equation}

I can solve characteristic equation for y, which can be
integrated to obtain $y = C_1(s)e^{-t},$ and the initial condition then yields $y = s^2e^{s^2}e^{-t}.$
I am not sure if I parametrized the equations incorrectly from the initial data, but I am having trouble obtaining $x(s,t)$ and $z(s,t)$ from here.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=x,\;\;\frac{dy}{dt}=-y,\;\; \frac{dz}{dt}=xz\quad\text{ is correct}$$
Or on the Charpit-Lagrange form :
$$dt=\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dy}{-y}=\frac{du}{xu}$$
A first characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dy}{-y}$:
$$xy=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation comes from $\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{du}{xu}$ :
$$e^{-x}u=c_2$$
General solution of the PDE on the form of implicit equation $c_2=F(c_1)$ :
$$e^{-x}u=F(xy)$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function.
$$\boxed{u(x,y)=e^xF(xy)}$$
Condition : $u(s,s^2)=1=e^sF(s^3)\quad\implies\quad F(s^3)=e^{-s}$ .

Let $X=s^3$
$$F(X)=e^{-X^{1/3}}$$
Now the function $F(X)$ is determied. We put it into the above general solution where $X=xy$ :
$$u(x,y)=e^xe^{-(xy)^{1/3}}$$
$$\boxed{u(x,y)=e^{x-(xy)^{1/3}}}$$